# Is it a good idea to mix the validation / testing data with the training data?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am working with a large dataset (e.g. large for a single machine) - with 1,000,000 examples.

I split my dataset to as follows: (80% Training Data, 10% Validation Data, 10% Testing Data). Every time I retrain the model, I shuffle the data first - such that some of the data from the validation / testing set ends up into the training set and vice versa.)

My thinking is this:

1. Ideally I would want all possible available data for the model to learn. The more the better - for improved accuracy.
2. Even though 20% of the data is dedicated to validation and testing, that is still 100,000 examples per piece - (i.e. I may potentially miss out on some crucial data that exists within the validation or testing set that the previous training set may not have accounted for.)
3. Shuffling prevents the training set from learning order where it is not important (at least in my particular dataset).

Here is my workflow process:
[image]

- The Test Accuracy is more or less the equivalent to the Validation Accuracy (plus or minus 0.5%)

Per each retrain, the results usually ends up something like this: where the accuracy keeps improving (until it runs out of total epoch), but the validation accuracy ends up stuck at a particular percentage. I then save that model. Start the retraining process again. Shuffles data occurs. The training accuracy drops, but validation accuracy jumps up. The training accuracy improves until total epoch. The validation accuracy, converges downward (still greater than the previous run).

See Example:
[image]

I plan on doing this until the training accuracy data reaches 99%. (Note: I used Keras-Tuner to find the best architecture/model for my particular problem)

I can't help but think, that I am doing something wrong by doing this. From my perspective, this is just the model eventually learning all 1,000,000 examples. It feels like "mild overfitting" because of the shuffling per each retrain.

***Is it a good idea to mix the validation / testing data with the training data?
Am I wrong by doing it this way? If so, why should I not do this method? Is there a better way to approach this?***

Answer (score 2):

If you mix your test/validation data with training data, you then can not evaluate your model on that data, since that data has been seen by your model. The model evaluation is done on the basis of how well it is able to make predictions/classification **on data which your model has not seen** (assuming that the data you are using to evaluate your model is coming from the same distribution as your training data). If you also mix your test set data with training set data, you will eventually end up with really good test set accuracy since that data has been seen by your model, but it might not perform well on new unseen data coming from the same distribution.

If you are worried size of test/validation data, I suggest you further reduce the size of your test/validation data. Use 99.9% instead of 99%. Also, the random shuffling will take care of learning almost every feature of your data.

After all, my point is, never ever evaluate your model on the data it has seen before. It will always give you better results (assuming you have trained your model well untill it **memorizes** the training data). The validation data is used when you have multiple algorithms/models and you need to select one algorithm/model from all those available models. Here, the validation data is used to select the model. The algo/model which gives good results on validation data is selected (again you do not evaluate your model based on validation set accuracy, it is just used for the selection of the model.) Once you have selected your model based on validation set accuracy, you then evaluate it on new unseen data (called test data) and report the prediction/classification accuracy on test data as your model accuracy.